# How to use a string to specify a property or method at run time. Error: Public member 'Temp' on type 'Range' not found

Tags: excel, vba

How to use a string to specify a property or method at run time.

I'm trying to execute the following code by dynamically assigning the excel property to a string.

Original

```
Range("A1:A20").NumberFormat = @
```

My Edited Version

```
Dim Temp As String = "NumberFormat"

Range("A1:A20").Temp = @
```

This throws me the error

> Public member 'Temp' on type 'Range' not found

Now how can I resolve this error, I want to use the same code and dynamically assign multiple properties (NumberFormat, WrapText, Font.Size, etc) to Temp

Comment: I don't see the point in just swapping `NumberFormat` property name for `Temp` even if you could. You are just creating a middle man operator.... can you expand on your problem some more. I suspect this is an XY problem

Comment: When the description of a tag says **THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL. DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR NEW QUESTIONS**, that means you should not use the tag. Please read tag descriptions before adding them to be sure they're the most appropriate for your question.

Comment: `Dim Temp As String = "NumberFormat"` is VB.net, not VBA.... but you can use [`CallByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function) in VBA probably to achieve this: `CallByName Range("A1:A20"), Temp, VbLet, "@"`.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @BigBen's comment:

```
Sub tester()

    ApplyValue Selection.Cells(1), "NumberFormat", "@"
    ApplyValue Selection.Cells(1), "HorizontalAlignment", xlRight
    ApplyValue Selection.Cells(1), "Font.Bold", True
    ApplyValue Selection.Cells(1), "Font.Color", vbYellow
    ApplyValue Selection.Cells(1), "Interior.Color", vbRed

End Sub

'Set a named property of an object to a provided value
'Object to be affected may be at the end of a period-delimited "chain"
'  of "Object1.ChildObject" etc
Sub ApplyValue(obj As Object, propString, propVal)
    Dim o As Object, arr, x As Long
    arr = Split(propString, ".")
    Set o = obj
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If x <> UBound(arr) Then
            'not there yet - get the next object in the chain
            Set o = CallByName(o, arr(x), VbGet)
        Else
            'at the end of the chain, so set the property
            CallByName o, arr(x), VbLet, propVal
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```